# ORA-40474: invalid UTF-8 byte sequence in JSON data

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I am trying to parse JSON data to different columns in oracle. below is the sql I am running. I am not able to identify why I am getting json parse error. I have tried to replace non-ascii, non-printable characters but its still not working -

```
select * from  (select '{
  "data": [
    {
      "note": "Yeah, it still wonb\u00000019t let me. Not sure why.\r\n\r\nThanks man!\r\n\r",
      "id": 0
    }
  ]
}' json_data from dual)i ,json_table( i.json_data  , '$.data[*]'  
                COLUMNS (
ID varchar2(4000) path '$.id',
note varchar2(4000) path '$.note'
  )  )
```

Comment: I do not have a 12c database to test on but a straight copy paste from your question works fine in 19c database... So there are a number of possible  ideas.. 1) there was a non-printable character you missed and posting removed this (try copy paste from your post) 2) The character set you are using will not handle one of the characters (my NLS_CHARACTERSET is WE8MSWIN1252) 3) Oracle has fixed somthing in between 12 and 19 (search metalink for a patch)

Comment: It is working fine in Oracle 12c with character set AL32UTF8

Comment: Thanks Shaun and Tejash.  I tried copy paste from here and it is not working on my side in Oracle 12c character set WE8MSWIN1252

Comment: these characters are causing error - \u but dont know what is the error. If I remove \u its working fine

Comment: If you google \u0000 you will find that this equates to the null character....  not sure what you were trying to print her but if you want the literal text you would need to escape the 'u' so would need wonb\/u00000019t. Currently when I do it it prints "Yeah, it still wonb0019t let me. Not sure why."

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from (select '{'||chr(10)||
             '  "data": ['||chr(10)||
               json_object(key 'note'   value 'Yeah, it still won''t \\u00000019 let me. Not sure why.'
                          ,key 'id'     value 0)||
             '   ]'||chr(10)||
             '}'     json_data
      from dual) i
,     json_table(
         i.json_data
       , '$.data[*]'
         columns(
             id varchar2(4000) path '$.id'
           , note varchar2(4000) path '$.note'));
```

hth
(I tested this query on Oracle 19 btw)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).